# FieldValue.arrayUnion not updating all fields swift firestore

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm trying to use arrayUnion to add elements to multiple array fields at once, for some reason it intermittently doesn't update all of the fields, and the fields which aren't updated seem to be random.

I can't find anyone else with the same issue. As far as I can tell from the documentation I'm doing this correctly, only issue I can see if that perhaps I'm adding elements to too many arrays at once. any ideas what could be wrong?

Code below:

```
var selectedDate = Date()
var pointsScoreString = ""
if oppositionScoreBool == false {
    pointsScoreString = pointsScoreText.text ?? "0"
} else {
    pointsScoreString = "\(pointsScoreText.text ?? "0.0")-\(pointsScoreTextOp.text ?? "0.0")"
}
let pointsScoreUser = Int(pointsScoreText.text!) ?? 0
let pointsScoreOp = Int(pointsScoreTextOp.text!) ?? 0
var notesText = " "
if notesTextView.text != "Notes" {
    notesText = notesTextView.text
}

firestoreDatabase.collection("trackers").document(documentId).updateData([
    "rSyncDateArray" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([selectedDate]), 
    "rSyncEventNameArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion([eventNameText.text!]), 
    "rSyncPointsArrayUser": FieldValue.arrayUnion([pointsScoreUser]), 
    "rSyncPointsArrayOp": FieldValue.arrayUnion([pointsScoreOp]), 
    "rSyncPointsStringArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion([pointsScoreString]), 
    "rSyncEventNotes" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([notesText])
])
print("RESULT DATA SAVED - 1 points")
```

Pretty new to coding still, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Chris, have you tried to log the data while updating to check the intermittent behavior?

Comment: No I didn't know you could do that @MarcAnthonyB can you point me in the direction of how?

Comment: Resorted to using a closure and saving the full array with additional data in. I don't think the arrayUnion functionality was designed to handle multiple updates at once

Comment: Hi @Chris, please post it as an answer so it would help the community. Regarding the logging of data, you may check it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs). Thank you.